# Is using AMP software like WAMP, MAMP, XAMPP a good idea?

Tags: php, xampp, wamp, mamp

I know that softwares like WAMP, XAMPP save a lot of difficult configuration time. But, besides this, Is this a good idea? I, on the other would like to stick to traditional method and install each component seperately and use them.

Comment: The technical skill of the installer/maintainer and the application demands all affect the answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it's a good idea. Easy configuration means, saved time. Saved time means, projects complete fast. Fast completion of projects means more projects and More projects mean more money. :) lol

Comment: This is an overly simplistic point of view. For development/tests that's a valid option, but the configuration should be fine tuned in production environments.

Answer (score 4):

These all-in-one solutions are designed for quick setup and testing. I don't think I would use them in a live or commercial environment, where the scalability and reliability become a major concern. For a development platform, a very small-scale deployment, or a temporary solution, they are quick and easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

I'd agree with JYelton in that it's meant for quick setup, and isn't meant for live or commercial environments. For myself, coming from a .NET shop, and deciding to work on a small, personal PHP site on the side, a WAMP approach worked quite well for getting my server stack up and running quickly.

It saved me time that I was able to invest elsewhere - finding a PHP toolchain that worked for me, documenting server versus development environment differences, documenting a dev environment setup, and setting up a staging sub-domain for testing on a live server.

I think it's worth learning the individual pieces, if for no other reason than intellectual enlightenment. If you plan on working in web development, understanding the configuration for a web server stack is a very good thing; both understanding the conceptual stack and the actual configuration and implementations of your particular server configuration.